# Analyze a string for boolean operator

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'm trying to make a search function for one of my programs, my plan is to let users search content with something like this

```
((network || system) && (ip || dns || bios)) && (version || name)
```

so whenever a string matches this search term like

```
NETWORK: ****** DNS: ******* NAME: *******
```

or

```
SYSTEM BIOS VERSION: ****
```

it will recognize  it.

But i can't figure out how to implement this.

I thought about working through the whole search term and splitting it up to it's pieces but since i don't know how many AND or OR's are going to be in there i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried with regular expressions ? With capture groups it could be a very handy way to parse complex strings

Comment: Why not just use three search variables instead of trying to parse a string?  Then you wouldn't have to do any parsing.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I'm aware that somewhere along the way String.Contains is needed, but first I have to split up the search statement to get the needed strings and the relation between them.

@DStanley If i understand you correctly you mean it like this -> `network dns name` which would match my first example ?

Comment: I'd use IndexOf instead of String.Contains (considering case sensitivity), but considering the complexity of your query I'd recommend using a parser.

Comment: @UrsKröll No I'm saying _use separate variables_.  Why make the users enter a concatenated string. Unless you want to support any combination of `AND/OR` in any order, in which case you need a lexical parser (which won't be easy and will need a LOT of testing).

Answer (score 3):

In order to do this, you need more than just some string comparison. Actually you are looking for a parser that can parse statements and form something understandable out of it, whether that is for you.

I would recommend to take a look at [ANTLR](http://antlr.org), which is a parser/lexer. It has templates for C# too.

Comment: ANTLR is a nice tool but I'm afraid it's a bit complicated for OP, especially on a so simple need ;).

Comment: If the first line is an example of the search query than he does need something more advanced.

Comment: @Urs: need more help?

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things:

1. Restrict yourself to simple cases like "abc && def" then you 
   may use simple string manipulations
2. Complex expression (like in your question), then you need a parser.

Is is not too hard to write a simple parser yourself (if you know enough about the theory behind it). Else use a ready made toolkit like [@Patrick suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28300554/993547) (ANTLR) which involves quite some learning curve also.